# How to pass the function with NSTimer

Tags: swift, nstimer

```
private func requestNewTracksWithDelaySec(delay:Double, onGet:(Array<JSON>)->()) {
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(delay, target: self, selector: Selector("getNewTracksRequest:"), userInfo: onGet, repeats: false)
}
```

Then, Occur Error

```
"Extra argument 'selector' in call"
```

How can I pass the function?

Comment: Don't use "Selector("getNewTracksRequest:")", instead use "getNewTracksRequest:".

Comment: Thank you. but, error is still existing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the function in which you want to execute my code.

Try this.

```
private func requestNewTracksWithDelaySec(delay:Double, onGet:(Array<JSON>)->()) {
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(delay, target: self, selector: Selector("getNewTracksRequest:"), userInfo: onGet, repeats: false)
}
```

Then declare the function.

```
func getNewTracksRequest(){

println("Hello")

}
```